# How do I create a list with no predefined length and assigned values to their positions, in Dart?

Tags: list, dart, declare

I'm developing my first application with Dart, which had previously created in JavaScript.
In my statement in JavaScript I have declared a List, and I assign values ​​to the first three positions, as seen here:

```dart
serpF var = new List ();
serpF [0] = 10;
serpF [1] = 10;
serpF [2] = 10;
```

How I can do the same in Dart? I have read the documentation of Lists and Arrays of Seth Ladd in "http://blog.sethladd.com/2011/12/lists-and-arrays-in-dart.html" and I've tried everything, but it is being impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javaScript code does not work in Dart because it is an error to access past the end of the List.  Dart is like many other languages as this is a way to catch logic errors.

What you can do is add elements to a List:

```dart
var serpF = new List();  // This list has length == 0.
serpF.add(10);
serpF.add(10);
serpF.add(10);
```

You can use *method cascades* to shorten the code:

```dart
var serfP = [];
serpF..add(10)..add(10)..add(10);
```

If you do know the length, you might also try one of the other List constructors:

```dart
var serfP = new List.filled(3, 10);
var serfP = new List.generate(3, (i) => 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

I addition to what Stephen suggests you can also do:

```dart
var serpF = [10, 10, 10];
```

or

```dart
var serpF = new List();
serpF.length = 3;
serpF[0] = 10;
serpF[1] = 10;
serpF[2] = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `List.generate()` constructor:

```dart
var list = new List.generate(3, (_) => 10, growable: true);
print(list); // Prints [10, 10, 10].
```

The first arg specifies the number of elements in the list, the second arg takes a callback to give each element a value, and the third arg ensures that the list is not fixed-width.